# Automate drag & drop from chromium embedded-window to another OS application/Windows Explorer

Tags: selenium, chromium-embedded

I wanted to get drag and drop automated from a chromium-embedded window to another application/windows explorer window. Is it something that can be automated via Selenium or similar framework?

Answer (score 1):

Roughly talking: Selenium works only inside web viewport.
If you want to drag and drop item from Chromium embedded-window to Windows Explorer window you can try `White` framework (if you are on Windows platform).

Introduction to `White`:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/289028/White-An-UI-Automation-tool-for-windows-applicatio

Discussion related "drag and drop" in `White`:
http://white.codeplex.com/discussions/271672

I'd go like this:
 1. Use Selenium (ChromeDriver) to detect position of the item inside Chromium window.
 2. Use desktop automation tool (like `White`, `UI Automation` or even call Windows API directly) to detect position of Chromium window.
 3. Calculate absolute position of item (using data from first and second step).
 4. Perform "drag and drop" using desktop automation tool (based on data from third step).

Comment: I agree with you that selenium cannot be used for this requirement and using some desktop automation tool is the ideal solution. However i needed to automate this for both mac and win and hence I tried "sikuli"(http://www.sikuli.org/), which works well if the UI is same in all platforms.